# Ionic Bluetooth-Classic plugin to communicate with native to native

Tags: android, cordova, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, ionic4

**AIM**

To communicate between android to android, iOS to iOS and windows to windows devices using Bluetooth-Classic.

**What I have tried**

I have tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-bluetooth-serial this plugin but it has limitations which is not meeting my expectation(Neither supported for android to android nor for iOS to iOS).

I tried google search but I'm not able to find one.

**Issue**

> Can any one help me where to start from or any plugin you suggest.
>
> I am not familiar with native plugin code. If there are any suggestion for me to work on, which file and method will help a lot to achieve android to android communication